# How do I delete files within a directory and subdirectories but not the folders?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

How do I delete files within a directory and subdirectories but not the folders?

I need to be able to do this on the Linux command line.

With `rm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### GNU `find` and “modern” versions

GNU `find` (the one shipped with Linux distributions) and the `find` present in recent macOS versions<sup>[Which ones?]</sup> has a `delete` option.

```
find . -type f -delete
```

This deletes all finds in the current directory and subdirectories. It leaves the directories in place.

This is way more efficient than methods below, as it doesn't have to fork a new process with `rm`. It is also more secure when considering file paths.

The GNU manual for find has [a very extensive section on deleting files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files).

#### Traditional `find`

Traditional `find` may not have a `-delete` option. In this case you can use the `exec` option to do something with the matched files – in this case `rm`ing them.

```
find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

#### `find` piped into `xargs`

You can also use the `find` output to feed into `xargs`, which will take the file paths as arguments for a `rm` command.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

The `-print0` option is necessary to avoid breaking things with filenames containing whitespace. Generally, don't use such a thing without this option, it's highly insecure.

Comment: the GNU find works on ubuntu, very simple. thanks for your post :)

Comment: GNU find `-delete` option also works for macOS.

Comment: @uotonyh Thanks, answer updated. It's been more than 10 years since — `-delete` is now more widely supported.